# Unable to download specific version of libxdmcp from Ubuntu archives

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, download, package-management, packages

I'm trying to install 3D printing software (Klipperscreen) on a 2012 Macbook Pro running Linux Mint 21.3. The installation script tries to fetch **libxdmcp-dev_1.1.3-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb** (http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxdmcp/libxdmcp-dev_1.1.3-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb). It fails with a connection timeout. Mirrors closer to my location result in the same error (http://plug-mirror.rcac.purdue.edu/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxdmcp/libxdmcp-dev_1.1.3-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb).

I'm wondering if the issue is actually with the archive site, not my local machine. If I visit archive.ubuntu.com (or mirrors) using the browser, I am unable to download **libxdmcp-dev_1.1.3-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb**, however, I can successfully download other builds, such as **libxdmcp-dev_1.1.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb**. I waited 6 days to see if the issue would clear up, but no such luck.

With some Googling, I was able to find another mirror site from which I was able to successfully download **libxdmcp-dev_1.1.3-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb** using a browser (https://mirror.coganng.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxdmcp/libxdmcp-dev_1.1.3-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb). However, this cognanng.com site is not listed in the Mint Software Sources GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [link](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxdmcp/libxdmcp-dev_1.1.3-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb) that fails is HTTP-only, and it might be failing because that site does not provide HTTPS. In my *browser*, I get a warning for, but if I allow it to proceed, it *does* succeed, downloading ~26 kB.

Then I downloaded the file from your [alternate link](https://mirror.coganng.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxdmcp/libxdmcp-dev_1.1.3-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb), diffed it with the first, and **found it identical**.

You could modify the script to use the HTTPS site, but before you do so, **confirm my experiment** that the files are, indeed, identical.

Comment: How were you able to download the file from archive.ubuntu.com? The browser does give a warning and I tell it to proceed. I am able to download 1,114 bytes of 25.9 kB, at which point the download rate drops to 0 B/s and hangs indefinitely. I have tried Firefox, Edge, and Chrome. I've also tried this over my work VPN. I've also tried from a machine running Linux Mint and a different machine running Windows 11.

Comment: I went ahead and manually installed the cognanng.com file and then the Klipperscreen  install script ran successfully. No editing the install script was necessary. Thank you for checking that the files were the same!